# Get word count and average length from frequency dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

If I have a frequency dictionary that includes the words from a text as the keys and the number of times they appear in the text as the value. How can I get the word count and average length by making sure to take into account of words that appear more than once? Right now what I have is to just make a list of the keys (since they are the words) and then just use len() for word count.

```
wordcount=len(list(freq.keys()))
report["count:"]=wordcount
#for average length:
avg=list(freq.keys())
average=sum(map(len,avg))/len(avg)
report["avglen"]=average
```

Comment: `len(freq)` is enough to get a word count here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sum` function and `dict.values()`:

```
freq = { 'test' : 10, 'rep' : 100 }
wordcount = sum(freq.values())
average   = sum(len(w) * c for w, c in freq.items()) / wordcount
print(wordcount, average)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_of_words  = int(raw_input("Enter the number of words. "))

word_dict = {}

for i in range(number_of_words):
    word = raw_input("Enter word. ")
    if word in word_dict:
        word_dict[word] += 1
    else:
        word_dict[word] = 1

print word_dict

print sum([len(word)*word_dict[word] for word in word_dict])/number_of_words
```

A very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143947/word-frequency-counter-python/20145320#20145320